# Using an audio amplifier with differential outputs with headphones

Tags: amplifier, audio, class-d

I'm planning to use TPA2012D2 (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa2012d2.pdf) audio amplifier from TI from my headphone audio project.
This amplifier has a differential outputs for left and right audio channels.

My question is, how do I connect this to an headphone jack where I have a common ground for both channels? 
Is it possible to use just the OUTL- and OUTR-, and ground the OUTL+ and OUTR+?

(This is the typical application schematic found in the datasheet)
[image]

Comment: You can generally ignore the OUT- outputs, simply use OUT+ and GND.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each channel output is a H bridge therefore you cannot cross connect speaker wires to form a common 0V. You could use a transformer to convert a balanced output (H bridge output) to a single ended output and you'd need one transformer per output.

You might be able to use the half-H bridge outputs but distortion and other problems may occur due to imbalanced loading. Read the data sheet to see what it says.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. This is the answer I was looking for, the theory behind it. Thanks so much! I'll switch to another device as @pjc50 proposed.

Comment: There are plenty of options: LM4880, LM4910, MAX97200, TDA1308, MAX4298, LM4809/10 etc.. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=headphone+amplifier+chip&espv=2&biw=1231&bih=923&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO-6OqlrTOAhVIJ8AKHXE8B50QsAQIUg#imgrc=F2DhUjClgW9G-M%3A

Answer (score 3):

Look at the other example schematic which shows a headphone socket:

[image: Schematic]

It's driven from a TPA4411 instead. I think the TPA2012 is a bit high-powered for headphones anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I need to switch to another device as you say, and from the answer that Andy aka gave. Thanks guys!

Comment: .. TI have of course reccomended a more expensive part, whereas a quick check of digikey suggests http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4808.pdf LM4808 - note the much lower output power into a higher impedance. Headphones are 16-32ohm rather than 4-8ohm.

Comment: This is the right answer. The amp is used for the loudspeakers in the handeld device, not for the headphones.